# serving video from springboot?

Tags: video, stream

I'm writing both server and client side application that should stream video from server written using Spring boot to angular 2 app.what is the best approach to serve video files in springboot?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  It allows you to build content services using similar a programming model to Spring Data.  It supports video streaming out of the box.

In that github org there are several examples floating around that show Spring Content working with angular and jhipster generated front-ends.

Comment: Is there any example implementation for video streaming from web cam with Spring Content?

Comment: atm Spring Content is more about streaming stored content rather than live content.  That said, I suppose that would be feasible to create a special type of Store to represent a webcam and make it a read-only store.   Or do you also want to store what is being streamed?

Comment: might require to record video to a file too at a later stage. but initially just need to show it.

Comment: would you be able to include that in any recent updates to Spring Content - video streaming along with recording(to a file) option?

Answer (score 2):

Look into red5 server http://red5.org/
It is built specifically for these kind of applications and you can use java and spring.

Also look into Xuggler http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/