# How to stream video using spring boot (webflux) and angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, video-streaming, spring-webflux

Hey I'm building a video streaming application using spring boot and angular. I think API call on angular side is not giving desired type of response.

Have a look at my controller

```
      private static String FORMAT  = "classpath:videos/%s.mp4";
    
        @Autowired
        private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    
        @GetMapping(value = "video/{title}", produces = "video/mp4")
        public Mono<Resource> getVideos(@PathVariable String title, @RequestHeader(value = "Range") String range) {
            System.out.println("Range in bytes : "+range);
            return Mono.fromSupplier(()->resourceLoader.getResource(String.format(FORMAT,title)));
        }
```

And this is my service in angular

```
  getVideo(title: any): Observable<any> {
    let header = new HttpHeaders();
    return this.http
      .get<[]>(BASIC_URL+`api/video/${title}`, 
        {headers:this.createRange()}
        )
      .pipe(
        tap((_) => this.log('Getting video chunks')),
        catchError(this.handleError<[]>('Error getting video', []))
      );
  }
```

And here is HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <h4>Spring Boot Video streaming</h4>
    <video [src]='videoInByte' width="700px" height="400px" controls  preload="none">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [serving video from springboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022532/serving-video-from-springboot)