# I want to check the bar path after uploading a workout video in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, spring, spring-boot, flask

I am currently developing a website with Spring Boot and Javascript.

I found a python repository that allows you to put in a workout video, specify a zone, and see the path of the barbell.

I needed cv2(opencv), dlib, numpy package for this.
The sequence was: import video -> select region -> run -> check bar path . The run was successful.

But I want to show this in HTML, not in an opencv window, and provide a way to specify a region.
Any suggestions on how to do this?

I considered Flask, but since the screen is rendered by Spring Boot, I think Flask and Spring Boot can only communicate JSON. Is it possible to display it on the screen?

Or I've also considered javascript, I could use opencv2, but I think I'll run into issues with dlibs or numpy.

I also thought about rendering an html screen in Flask and fetching it as an iframe tag from the Springboot server.

Has anyone done anything like this before or can point me in the right direction?

*I'm asking through a translator, so my English sentences may be strange, please forgive me

Comment: you mention a lot of technologies here and the only relevant sentence is (correct me if I am wrong) `I want to build a website that serves videos with SpringBoot and JS`. Yes it is possible, usually you would store the videos in some object storage or whatever and only send the link from Backend (Sprinboot) in JSON and frontend would embed/render the video based on the link. Alternatively you could also store the video in you own database and Backend could transmit it to frontend - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022532/serving-video-from-springboot)

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, in my case, it's not just streaming, I have a process where the user uploads a video of a barbell workout, specifies the zones they want, and then checks the path of the barbell.

Comment: but that functionality (of uploading a video and specifying zones, etc) already is implemented, is it not? And therefore not relevant to your question?